Lightbox2 - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jQuery')
The problem
I am trying to implement the lightbox2 gallery scripts into my Laravel project. The bundler seems to nicely bundle the needed files but the script is blocked from executing with the following error in my console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jQuery')

at this location: github - lightbox2:dist/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js:11021
Setup

Framework : Laravel 11 - Breeze (blade)
Bundler : Vite 5

I am trying to add a Lightbox2 gallery to one of my pages, I had some trouble getting it working with the npm package so I went the other option of downloading a zip from the repository and included the following files manually into my resources:

dist/css/lightbox.css
dist/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js (since laravel does not include jquery as a default)

My lightbox.css is imported in my app.js (resources/js/app.js)
My lightbox-plus-jquery is included in my Vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/js/lightbox/lightbox-plus-jquery.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});

And my Vite scripts are imported using the @vite method in my blade file.
@vite([
    'resources/css/style.css', 
    'resources/js/app.js',
    'resources/js/lightbox/lightbox-plus-jquery.js',
])

My blade view is simply looping over the array of images and creating the suggested structure from the lightbox docs.
<div class="gallery" >
    @if($project->gallery)
        @foreach($project->gallery as $image)
            <a href="{{ asset($image) }}" data-lightbox="gallery-item" >
                <img src="{{ asset($image) }}" alt="{{$title . ' : ' . $image}}" />
            </a>
        @endforeach 
    @endif
</div>


Were you not using jQuery before in your project, or was that embedded already?

@CBroe no this is indeed the first use of jQuery in this project. I checked Laravel, but it seems it's not included out of the box neither.

Sounds to me as if this version of the script explicitly needs the jQuery alias, instead of the usual $ - but that your bundler probably rewrites that somehow. Try and embed jQuery yourself, and then just the lightbox.js version, and see if that changes anything.

It looked like I was not able to embed it myself, I tried to import it in the bootstrap.js file,  use an asset('url') in my blade, used inline script tags, but the error persisted. After looking into what you said I read that Vite might have deffered scripts by default, which is causing the jQuery to be called before initiatilazion.. Eventually I tried a variant of the package (fslightbox) and that worked. Thanks for the information though! got me on the right track of understanding the issue.
